# Is it possible to create a grid of squares using CSS Grid layout?

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-grid

I want to create a grid of equal squares. I've been looking at CSS Grid as I thought it was possible to create equal width and height areas in grids. But I don't see anything in the Grid spec about it. The basic code is like this:

```css
.squaregrid {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.cell {
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="squaregrid">
  <div class="cell">A</div>
  <div class="cell">B</div>
  <div class="cell">C</div>
  <div class="cell">D</div>
  <div class="cell">E</div>
  <div class="cell">F</div>
  <div class="cell">G</div>
  <div class="cell">H</div>
  <div class="cell">I</div>
</div>
```

I get a 3x3 grid but the height of each "cell" is just the size of the letters (because the `fr` unit makes the rows' height relative to each other, not relative to the column width).

I can use a fixed size instead of `1fr` but then of course it's not responsive.

I'm aware of the `padding-bottom` trick which is used to maintain an aspect ratio, but that involves multiple wrappers for every cell, plus if I'm doing that there's not really any need to use Grid, I can use regular divs or flexbox.

Any other solutions out there?

Answers on the "duplicate" question do not solve the problem.

Comment: Are you completely against JS? Would be pretty simple to accomplish that way...

Comment: The latest news on this: https://cssence.com/code/2018-01-21-maintaining-aspect-ratio-with-css-grid  You'll need a wrapper element no matter which approach you choose.

Answer (score 4):

> I get a 3x3 grid but the height of each "cell" is just the size of the letters (because the `fr` unit makes the rows' height relative to each other, not relative to the column width).

When you say this...

```
grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr);
```

which is a shorthand for this...

```
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr
grid-template-areas: none
```

you're creating a 3x3 grid where columns and rows take an equal distribution of free space.

But you want all cells to be square.

Unless the container has the exact same dimensions, the cells cannot be square using `fr` units.

You've set a maximum width to the container (`max-width: 600px`), but have no defined height. Therefore, expect to see rectangular cells.

If you want squares, try something like this:

```css
.squaregrid {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
.cell {
    background: #ddd;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="squaregrid">
    <div class="cell">A</div>
    <div class="cell">B</div>
    <div class="cell">C</div>
    <div class="cell">D</div>
    <div class="cell">E</div>
    <div class="cell">F</div>
    <div class="cell">G</div>
    <div class="cell">H</div>
    <div class="cell">I</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vw` units to make it responsive. Instead of `1fr` use `30vw` like so:

```css
.squaregrid {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template: repeat(3, 30vw) / repeat(3, 30vw);
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
.cell {
    background: #ddd;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="squaregrid">
    <div class="cell">A</div>
    <div class="cell">B</div>
    <div class="cell">C</div>
    <div class="cell">D</div>
    <div class="cell">E</div>
    <div class="cell">F</div>
    <div class="cell">G</div>
    <div class="cell">H</div>
    <div class="cell">I</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this only works when the grid is spanning the entire page. The max-width doesn't work.